# possible clear jquery `one` method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its possible to clear jquery `one` property? for example given html

```
    <div id="button">button</div>

    <div id="clearOneProperty">clear one property</div>
```

and js

```
$("#button").one("click", function () {
    alert("blah");
});

$("#clearOneProperty").on("click", function () {
    // clear "one" property, that is after this event,  I want "#button"  to work again
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/RzzCu/2/

So, if click `#button` div, alert happened only one times right?

And I want that, at click on `#clearOneProperty`, reset one property. Its possible?

P.S. I am not asking how to make this with other ways, I am interest exact: "possible clear jquery `one` method?". Thanks.

Comment: When you say "clear one() method" do you mean, re-attach it so that `#button` can be clicked again, or do you mean remove the `one()` event so that it cannot be clicked?

Comment: `re-attach it so that #button can be clicked again`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
function bindButton() {
    $("#button").unbind('click').one("click", function() {
        alert("blah");
    });
}

bindButton();

$("#clearOneProperty").on("click", function() {
    bindButton();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RzzCu/11/)

Answer (score 3):

The **[one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** unbinds its self on first invocation as stated "The first form of this method is identical to .bind(), `except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation"`, **[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** **So you need to bind it again**.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/RzzCu/7/)**

```
$("#button").one("click", onefunction);

function onefunction() {
    alert("blah");
}
$("#clearOneProperty").one("click", function() {       
    $("#button").one("click", onefunction);
});​
```

Comment: This is really the only clean answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just rebind it inside the function.

```
$("#button").one("click", function () {
    alert("blah");
});

$("#clearOneProperty").one("click", function () {
    $('#button').one("click", function () {
    alert("blah");
});
});
```

here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RzzCu/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method

```
$("#button").unbind();
```

Comment: Note the OP wants to re-attach the event, not unbind it.

Comment: I think that the OP wants the contrary : bind again the button when it is resetted.

Comment: A good example of what the OP wants is for example choose a friend from your friend list, append a chat form to some TAB.When click to close the tab bind the one function again to the friend list, so the tab can be opened again.If not use one in the friend list, multiple instances of this "friend" will show up in the TAB list.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#button').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Note the OP wants to re-attach the event, not unbind it.