# Optimising Jquery to avoid double swap on images

Tags: jquery, image, attributes, swap

Problem: Images double fade on click.

Scenario:

Upon page load, a user is presented with 6 brand images. Each brand can be clicked and the 6 brand images swap to specific images with wrapped links to elsewhere on my site.

One brand, the top left, with alt "S support a" has several products. None of the other brands have this range, so only this image has need for extra code.

When the user clicks this brand, product images take the place of the brands, and the grid also modifies to take the new image size so everything is kept neat.

All but one of these images are wrapped with links to external pages. Only the top left image has a further set of image swaps.

This is where my problem occurs. Upon clicking this image, the fadeOut and fadeIn animations fire twice. It seems that the click the button fires the function despite me giving them different ID's.

Add in the problem that I also want to include a "back" button should a user click the wrong brand

Things tried:

1. Changing the initial .on('click'...) to .one('click'...).
   This worked, but I also plan on giving each phase of the sequence a back button, so I will need to ensure the image can be click on again.
2. Attempted to use code from here: [possible clear jquery `one` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642817/possible-clear-jquery-one-method) but it did not produce the desired results exactly.
3. various functions within the original.

I'm not sure if there's anything else I can add other than I need a coffee :/

Code example:

```js
$(function() {

  var idlist = $("#shi,#bpi,#thi,#emi,#eti,#jmi,#bl4,#ihi,#umi,#bl3,#bl5");

  $("#shi").on('click', function() {
    $(idlist).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $("#gri").css("grid-gap", "160px 120px");
        $("#shi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Products/TVs/STVI-STVC.jpg").attr('id', "stvi").attr("height", "150").attr("alt", "STV Icon")
        $("#bpi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Products/Audio/SAVI-SAVC.jpg").attr('id', "savi").attr("height", "150").attr("alt", "S link").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
        $("#thi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Products/Audio/SPKI-SPKC.jpg").attr('id', "spki").attr("height", "150").attr("alt", "S link2").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
        $("#emi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Products/Audio/SHFI-SHFC.jpg").attr('id', "shfi").attr("height", "150").attr("alt", "SHI link").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
        $("#eti").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Products/Audio/SRAI-SRAC.jpg").attr('id', "srai").attr("height", "150").attr("alt", "SAR link").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
        $("#jmi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Products/SDA/SAPI-SAPC.jpg").attr('id', "sapi").attr("height", "150").attr("alt", "SAP link").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
        $("#bl3").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg").attr('id', "bl1").attr("alt", "Blank 1")
        $("#bl4").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Products/SDA/SMWI-SMWC.jpg").attr("id", "smwi").attr("height", "150").attr("alt", "SMW").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
        $("#bl5").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg").attr('id', "bl1").attr("alt", "Blank 1")
        $("#ihi").text("Which Sharp product do you need help with?").attr('id', "ihis")
        $("#umi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/SHI-SHC.svg").attr('id', "#shih")
      })
      .fadeIn(500)
  });
})

//2nd SH Event

$(document).on('click', '#stvi', function() {
  $("#stvi,#savi,#spki,#shfi,#srai,#sapi,#smwc,#ihis").fadeOut(300, function() {
      $("#gri").css("grid-gap", "100px 100px")
      $("#stvi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/IMI-QSC.svg").attr("id", "imi").attr("alt", "S Support").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
      $("#savi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/IMI-QSC.svg").attr("id", "faq").attr("alt", "S FAQ").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
      $("#spki").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/IMI-QSC.svg").attr("id", "faa").attr("alt", "S A.FAQ").wrap("<a href='https://www.goingsomeplace.com'>")
      $("#shfi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg").attr("id", "bl1").attr("alt", "Blank 1").unwrap(["#shfi"])
      $("#srai").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg").attr("id", "bl1").attr("alt", "Blank 1").unwrap(["#srai"])
      $("#sapi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg").attr("id", "bl1").attr("alt", "Blank 1").unwrap(["#sapi"])
      $("#smwi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg").attr("id", "bl1").attr("alt", "Blank 1").unwrap(["#smwi"])
      $("#ihis").text("Support - S")
      $("#umi").attr('src', "images/2021_images/Logos/BPI-BPC.svg").attr("id", "#bpih")
    })
    .fadeIn(300)
})
```

```css
.shic {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #424750;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.1%;
}

.shtc {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 20%;
}


/*BRANDS*/

.isi {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

#gri {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  /* 3 columns */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 60px);
  /* 2 rows  */
  grid-gap: 100px 100px;
  /* 50 pixels of space added between rows and 100 pixels added between columns  */
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1%;
  border-bottom: #02AB9D;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

.gic {
  width: 300;
  height: 50;
  justify-content: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="ihi" class="ihc" style="color: #000000; font-family: Segoe, 'Segoe UI', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 1.5em;">
  Select the brand.
</h1>
<hr>
<section class="isc" id="isi">
  <div class="grc" id="gri">
    <div class="gic" id="gsh"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/SHI-SHC.svg" id="shi" class="shc" alt="S UK support" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 1, column 1-->
    <div class="gic" id="gbp"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/BPI-BPC.svg" id="bpi" class="bpc" alt="B support" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 1, column 2-->
    <div class="gic" id="gth"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/THI-THC.svg" id="thi" class="thc" alt="T support" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 1, column 3-->
    <div class="gic" id="gem"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/EMI-EMC.svg" id="emi" class="emc" alt="e support" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 2, column 1-->
    <div class="gic" id="get"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/ETI-ETC.svg" id="eti" class="etc" alt="E support" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 2, column 2-->
    <div class="gic" id="gjm"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/JMI-JMC.svg" id="jmi" class="jmc" alt="J support" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 2, column 3-->
    <div class="gic" id="gbl3"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg" id="bl3" class="blc" alt="blank 3" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 3, column 1-->
    <div class="gic" id="gbl4"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg" id="bl4" class="blc" alt="blank 4" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 3, column 2-->
    <div class="gic" id="gbl5"><img src="images/2021_images/Logos/BLI-BLC.svg" id="bl5" class="blc" alt="blank 5" width="300" height="50"></div>
    <!--Row 3, column 3-->
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You are changing the `id` of the image but the event listener is still cached so the original click function will also be executed. Just use a delegated listener `$(document).on('click', '#shi', function() {` like you do in the second function.

Comment: @Shikkediel  - yeah, that did it. And also, it sets me off to finish the entire page and its other functions.
I hope you can have some token of happiness in that you have unburdened me so damn much that I was on my knees in praise.
Such a simple thing it was. Thank you for taking the time to point it out. Very much.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).